# Video player controls not working in safari

Tags: angular, safari, html5-video

In my application, I have a div and inside the div I'm playing a video. The div have a click event which will take the application to another page.

**Expectation**

I should be able to play the video and click on the video controls and the page should not navigate.

**Actual**

Even if I'm trying to pause the video, the click event is triggered and the page is navigated.

Issue is only is safari, works fine in chrome.

```
<div (click)="displayContent()">
  <video  controls [src]="videoUrl" >Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any error in safari?

Comment: There is no error in this scenario. Browser is picking the click event of the parent div instead of the play/pause events.

Comment: Got it did you try ‘event.preventdefault();’?

Comment: I just need the player controls to work. Other area should pick the click event from the div. How to identify if its the player controls is clicked or the other part of the player is clicked.

Comment: You can create one directive to stop event propagation. so only that div click event is triggering other div click event is not triggering due to our directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive to stop the `event bubbling` here is the example.

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[stopEventBubbling]"
})
export class stopBubbling
{
    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you out.